# Solution-verification: $X\subset M_1$, $Y\subset M_2$ are compact in $M_1,M_2$ respectively, is $X\times Y$ compact in $M_1\times M_2$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

${\bf Proposition:}$ Suppose $X$ is compact in space $M_1$ and $Y$ is compact in space $M_2$. Then, $X\times Y$ (Cartesian product) is compact in the space $M_1\times M_2$.

${\bf Question:}$ The following is my proof. Is the statement true? Is my proof correct? (Sorry if this question is too elementary for general-topoloty tag. I just don't know who to ask.)

${\bf Proof:}$ Let $T_1$ be the topology on $M_1$, and $T_2$ be the topology on $M_2$. I define $T_3$, the topology on $T_1\times T_2$, as $T_3=\left\{ \mathcal{O}_\nu\times \mathcal{O}_\mu\mid \mathcal{O}_\nu\in T_1,\mathcal{O}_\mu \in T_2\right\}$. Now, suppose $W=\bigcup_{\theta\in \Theta}\mathcal{O}_\theta$, where $\mathcal{O}_\theta\in T_3$be an arbitrary open cover of $X\times Y$ in $T_1\times T_2$. Then, there exist an open cover of $X$, $\Lambda\in T_1$, and an open cover of $Y$, $\Delta\in T_2$, such that

$W=\bigcup_{\theta\in \Theta}\mathcal{O}_\theta=\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda,\beta\in \Delta}\mathcal{O}_\lambda\times\mathcal{O}_\beta$.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are compact in their respective space, there exist finite subcovers of $\Lambda$ and $\Delta$. Thus,
$W=\bigcup_{i=1}^m\bigcup_{j=1}^n\mathcal{O}_i\times \mathcal{O}_j$, where $\mathcal{O}_i\in \Lambda$ and $\mathcal{O}_j\in \Delta$, $1\leq i\leq n$, $1\leq j\leq m$. Thus, $W$ has a finite subcover. Therefore, it is compact.

${\bf \text{Edited Proof after correction:}}$ I have attempted to correct the proof after the suggestion to apply the tube lemma. So here it is. Consider any open set $N$ such that $X\times Y\subset N$. Then, by Tube Lemma https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tube_lemma (I am using the Generalized Tube Lemma 1 there.), there exist $U$ open in $M_1$ and $V$ open in $M_2$ such that $X\times Y\subset U\times V\subset N$.

Now I will prove $X\subset U$ and $Y\subset V$. Suppose $X$ is not a subset of $U$. Then, there exists an $x\in X$, $x\notin U$. Then, $\{x\}\times Y\subset X\times Y$ but $\{x\}\times Y$ is not a subset of $U\times V$. Thus, $X\times Y$ is not a subset of $U\times V$. Contradiction! Thus, $X\subset U$. Similarly, $Y\subset V$.

Now, $X$ is compact so $U$ has a finite subcover say $\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathcal{O}_i$. $Y$ is compact so $V$ has a finite subcover, say $\bigcup_{j=1}^m\mathcal{O}_j$.

$\bigcup_{i=1}^n\bigcup_{j=1}^m\mathcal{O}_i\times \mathcal{O}_j=\bigcup_{i=1}^n \mathcal{O}_i\times \bigcup_{j=1}^m\mathcal{O}_j\subset U\times V\subset N$. Since $\mathcal{O}_i\times \mathcal{O}_j$ are open for $1\leq i\leq n$, $1\leq j\leq m$ (I believe they should be the basis of the topology in the product space?). Thus, $N$ has a finite cover.

Comment: Your $T_3$ is not actually a topology. $(\mathcal{O}_a \times \mathcal{O}_b) \cup (\mathcal{O}_c \times \mathcal{O}_d)$ is not in general a Cartesian product.

Comment: "compact" is a property of topological spaces, hence it does not make sense to say "$X$ is compact in M". Unless you have your own, individual definition for this. But then you should let us know what your definition is.

Comment: @aschepler Isn't it enough to show that prodcut of two compact set is compact?

Comment: @DARK That's exactly the problem statement.

Comment: @aschepler Got it thank you

Comment: @Ulli We often say $[0,1]$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Or in other (more) words, the topology on $[0,1]$ induced by the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is compact.

Comment: @aschepler: yes, but this means that $[0,1]$ is compact as a topological space with the subspace topology. Or what is your definition of "compact in"?

Comment: @Ulli I would prefer "a compact subset of" over "compact in", true. And just to be clear, "$X$ is a compact subset of [topological space] $M=(Y,T_M)$" means $X \subseteq Y$ and $X$ with the subspace topology $\{\mathcal{O} \cap X \mid \mathcal{O} \in T_M\}$ is compact.

Comment: @aschepler: I completely agree. But then it is much easier to say (and to prove) "*if $X, Y$ are compact, then $X \times Y$ is compact*", rather than "*if $X, Y$ are subspaces of $M$ and $N$, which are compact as subspaces of $M$ and $N$, respectively, then $X \times Y$ is compact as a subspace of $M \times N$*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not quite right. Your $T_3$ is not a topology, it's a **basis** for a topology (it's not closed under arbitrary unions!). If I were a skeptical examiner I might want you to say a little more about where $\Lambda,\Delta$ came from; all you know is that, according to your (incorrect) definition of $T_3$, $\mathcal{O}_\theta=\mathcal{O}_\lambda\times\mathcal{O}_\beta$ for some open $\mathcal{O}_\lambda,\mathcal{O}_\beta$ but how do I know that $(\mathcal{O}_\lambda)_{\lambda}$ covers $M_2$? Recall that $A\times B\cup C\times D\neq(A\cup C)\times(B\cup D)$ but it looks a little bit like you thought that in your post.

But it's close to being right; it's morally got the right ideas. Firstly, compactness is an absolute notion, so we really just need to check that $X\times Y$ is compact if $X,Y$ are. Then you want to do a similar thing but ! $\mathcal{O}_\theta=\mathcal{O}_\lambda\times\mathcal{O}_\beta$ is *not* necessarily true; $T_3$ is a **basis** but it's usually not the whole topology. You therefore want to start talking about containments, like "for every $(x,y)\in X\times Y$ there is a $(x,y)\in\mathcal{O}_\lambda\times\mathcal{O}_\beta\subseteq\mathcal{O}_\theta$" and then it gets more tricky. If you get stuck, look at "the tube lemma".

The new version is still not quite right. First, let's take a sanity check: if $X\times Y\subset N$, then $N=X\times Y$; no tube lemma required. "$X$ is compact so $U$ has a finite subcover" - well, $U$ itself is a finite subcover of $X$... it is just one open set. Moreover, it is an open set *which you have not defined*. The $\mathcal{O}_i,U$ come from nowhere in your new proof. In a way, the causality is wrong: you seem to be thinking about constructing open covers, but actually I need to first *give* you a **completely arbitrary** open cover and then you need to construct a finite subcover. What's the setup? Given $X\times Y=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal{O}_i$. What have you argued? That if $N:=\bigcup_{i\in I}\mathcal{O}_i$ then $X\times Y\subseteq U\times V\subseteq N$ is true for some open $U,V$, which is trivial because we can take $U=X,V=Y$. Nothing more has been said; $X=U=\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathcal{O}_i$ is not true either and does not really make sense, the right hand side being subsets of $X\times Y$.

So what's the idea? Well we do want to use compactness of $X$ somehow so we do want to construct an open cover of $X$ related to the $\mathcal{O}_i$ and get a finite subcover from that. But we want to turn this back into something like $X\times Y=\bigcup_{j\in F}\mathcal{O}_j$, $F\subseteq I$ finite. How would the tube lemma help? Well, every $x\in X$ has $\{x\}\times Y$ covered by the $\mathcal{O}_\bullet$, and now we want to say we can enlarge that to some neighbourhood $U_x\times Y$ and cover it still by only finitely many $\mathcal{O}_\bullet$, and now we can think about the open cover associated to the $U_x,x\in X$.

Comment: Isn't it enough to show that prodcut of two compact set is compact?

Comment: @DARK yeah, so that's why I said "... an absolute notion, so we really just need to check that $X\times Y$ is compact if $X,Y$ are". Though I should be pedantic and say we should talk of compact spaces, not sets

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: @FShirke Thank you so much. You really point out where I messed up. Let me spend some time with your suggestions on how to correct the proof. Many thanks.

Comment: @curiosity You're welcome. You didn't mess up in a serious way, it's mostly just technical details from this point; you've got the idea. I guess there's one remaining technicality which is related to the tube lemma

Comment: @FShrike Would you kindly look over my edited proof? Did I miss anything? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @curiosity I've made some comments

Comment: @FShrike, thank you so much. I will study your comments and try again tonight. I really appreciate your help and patient.

Comment: @curiosity No worries, you're welcome. How to actually prove this is explained in detail on this site and in various places. If you get stuck you can always research an actual proof and then ask why that proof works, if it confuses you. I would say you should really make sure you know what you want to prove, it seems to me the definitions aren't quite straight in your head at the moment (- which is fine, compactness didn't click for me at first either)